# Time Series data used for estimation

Tags: time-series, bootstrap

I am new to Time Series analysis, but I have Time Series Data.  I am trying to estimate the total number of users of a product that occurred over a three month period. I have one observation of the total number of users at a given time for each day over a three month period.

For example, observation 1 occurred on January 1, 1:19 PM showed 8 users, observation 2 occurred on January 2,  4:51 AM showed 2 users, ect... The observations occur on 1 minute intervals at any time of the day.  The data has a positive trend and observations taken between 12 AM - 8 AM show less usage than observations taken between 4PM -12 AM, which show less usage than between 8 AM - 4PM.

Can I partition the data into three groups:

Group 1) 12 AM - 8 AM

Group2)  8 AM - 4PM

Group 3) 4PM - 12 AM

and bootstrap each group to find its mean number of users. If I can, would I have to check for autocorrelation, partial autocorrelation, or is there some other test I should be aware of.

Additionally, is it possible to find the values of the data points with the trend removed?

If someone has a different approach I would welcome any suggestions?